# Queueing Method Calls So That They Are Performed By A Single Thread In Clojure

Tags: clojure, parallel-processing, synchronization, orientdb

I'm building a wrapper around OrientDB in Clojure.  One of the biggest limitations (IMHO) of OrientDB is that the `ODatabaseDocumentTx` is not thread-safe, and yet the lifetime of this thing from `.open()` to `.close()` is supposed to represent a single transaction, effectively forcing transactions to occur is a single thread.  Indeed, thread-local refs to these hybrid database/transaction objects are provided by default.  But what if I want to log in the same thread as I want to persist "real" state?  If I hit an error, the log entries get rolled back too!  That use case alone puts me off of virtually all DBMS's since most do not allow named transaction scope management.  /soapbox

Anyways, OrientDB is the way it is, and it's not going to change for me.  I'm using Clojure and I want an elegant way to construct a `with-tx` macro such that all imperative database calls within the `with-tx` body are serialized.

Obviously, I can brute-force it by creating a sentinel at the top level of the `with-tx` generated body and deconstructing every form to the lowest level and wrapping them in a synchronized block.  That's terrible, and I'm not sure how that would interact with something like `pmap`.

I can search the macro body for calls to the `ODatabaseDocumentTx` object and wrap those in synchronized blocks.

I can create some sort of dispatching system with an agent, I guess.

Or I can subclass ODatabaseDocumentTx with synchronized method calls.

I'm scratching my head trying to come up with other approaches.  Thoughts?  In general the agent approach seems more appealing simply because if a block of code has database method calls interspersed, I would rather do all the computation up front, queue the calls, and just fire a whole bunch of stuff to the DB at the end.  That assumes, however, that the computation doesn't need to ensure consistency of reads.  IDK.

Comment: What kind of thread-unsafety are you encountering: a single "transaction object" can't be accessed by two threads, or is it that the database doesn't support concurrent writes?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for [Lamina](https://github.com/ztellman/lamina).

Comment: Could you explain how Lamina could be used?  I wouldn't want to force all computation to be serialized, just the I/O bits, and I don't see how Lamina would help with that.

Comment: Lamina lets you decouple computations from side effects in different ways using channels and pipelines. You can choose where to make things synchronous or asynchronous, and where operations are pulling or pushing downstream. I'm not completely seeing your problem, but I thought you could do your computations multithreaded and enqueue events on a channel for (single-threaded) consumption by a handler to deal with db calls. If you give an example of a simple scenario I could maybe help more.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use Executor with 1 thread in thread pool. Something like shown below. You can create a nice macro around this concept.

```
(import 'java.util.concurrent.Executors)
(import 'java.util.concurrent.Callable)

(defmacro sync [executor & body]
  `(.get (.submit ~executor (proxy [Callable] []
                             (call []
                               (do ~@body))))))

(let [exe (Executors/newFixedThreadPool (int 1))
      dbtx (sync exe (DatabaseTx.))]
  (do
    (sync exe (readfrom dbtx))
    (sync exe (writeto dbtx))))
```

The `sync` macro make sure that the body expression is executed in the executor (which has only one thread) and it waits for the operation to complete so that all operations execute one by one.

Comment: It seems to me that agents do pretty much the same thing.  The value of the agent itself would be the transaction, and `send` would apply a function with the transaction as the first arg and return the transaction to allow chaining.  How would this approach be different?

Comment: Agents uses a thread pool with many threads, so in case the constructor of the DB object creates some thread local stuff than that would be a problem in agent case as the expressions may execute on different thread